# How can I run the shell script "./segmentAndTrack.sh " in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to run  the shell script  "./segmentAndTrack.sh " in MATLAB. Can you tell me the procedure. I am newbie in shell script. Any kind of help welcome. My OS is linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run system commands a couple of ways in MATLAB:

```
!./segmentAndTrack.sh
```

or

```
[status,result] = system('./segmentAndTrack.sh');
```

or, in the case of a UNIX system

```
[status,cmdout] = unix(command)
```

Type 'doc unix' in the MATLAB terminal to get the full documentation for the function